# 'Auto Reconnect' JDBC connection property for Microsoft JDBC Driver

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, jdbc, hikaricp

Is there a jdbc connection property to auto reconnect to  SQL Server 2012 using  Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server. I don't find it and I am using hikari cp for connection pooling . Plz let me know if there is a better way to reconnect to DB if connection lost . I am using spring-hibernate with hikari cp to connect to SQL Server 2012 using Microsoft JDBC Driver .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `connectionTestQuery` setup at this [config file](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/blob/53e7427e63821eae9831a5c8db9d2fb74fa20903/src/test/resources/hibernate.properties).

Also [quoting the Documentation](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) as a word of caution about this parameter:

> connectionTestQuery If your driver supports JDBC4 we strongly
>   recommend not setting this property. This is for "legacy" databases
>   that do not support the JDBC4 Connection.isValid() API. This is the
>   query that will be executed just before a connection is given to you
>   from the pool to validate that the connection to the database is still
>   alive. Again, try running the pool without this property, HikariCP
>   will log an error if your driver is not JDBC4 compliant to let you
>   know. Default: none

Comment: Does the SQL Server driver support `Connection.isValid()`?