# How to set the Auto-Reconnect Property with Java using JDBC for MS SQL-Server 2012

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, connection

Is there any JDBC connection property to auto reconnect to SQL Server 2012 using JDBC Driver for SQL Server. I didn't find any. Please let me know if there is a better way to reconnect to the database, in case connection is lost.

Comment: I'm afraid not, it is not possible with any JDBC parameters!

Comment: Consider going through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968690/auto-reconnect-jdbc-connection-property-for-microsoft-jdbc-driver), for slightly similar discussion without any JDBC parameters!

Comment: How to Implement this N00b Pr0grammer kindly help me.

Comment: Did you check the link that I shared, you could use that or use any database connection pool for a quick start!

Comment: I am going that link but can't help me that link

Comment: Use a connection pool that does connection validation before handing out a connection.