# What causes Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect?

Tags: java, database, connection, database-connection, jtds

Occasionally losing connection to database in one of our environments.
Same code (automated tests) run perfectly fine in DEV environment, but when it comes to TEST - it loses connection sometimes.

From the logs I get this:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://HOST_HERE:PORT_HERE/DB_NAME_HERE;instance=sqlext;domain=DOMAIN_HERE;useNTLMv2=true;multiSubnetFailover=true
java.sql.SQLException: Network error IOException: Connection timed out: connect
```

using jtds driver

No problems with access rights.

- I connect to db - no problem,
- I checked connection string format here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx  looks correct
- I checked if indexes are missing - looks fine. Thought even if they were missing, it would be a problem in DEV environment too, but it's only in TEST.

Please direct me to the solution

Comment: It could be a network timeout for idle connections. You should look for an auto reconnect parameter but it may not be possible, reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42416198/how-to-set-the-auto-reconnect-property-with-java-using-jdbc-for-ms-sql-server-20